# Why does Google Drive download so much at startup?

Tags: google-drive

Every time my computer starts up Google Drive decides to download some 20-30 different files (which I can't find on the file system since its tick icons don't work that great and are still in sync mode when it isn't syncing). This amounts to some 180MB. Why? It wasn't downloading when I shut down the previous night, and there were no document changes to my account.

EDIT:

While I hadn't changed anything, my shared folders had new documents others had added in. These changes don't appear in "Recent" on the Google Drive web app it seems, but I found them on my filesystem with the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**it downloads all files in Drive to your disk**

Google Drive is a cloud drive storage that syncs all your <strike>documents</strike> files between your local storage and the cloud. While installing, it creates the necessary folder viz. Google Drive on your disk and downloads the software necessary to sync as well as all the <strike>documents</strike> files from the cloud.

apart from that, google drive is not reported to download any other content.
are you modifying content in the drive everyday? are you using any other service that ties to Drive? Have you tried removing drive and reinstalling it again?

Comment: would you mind posting your 'solution' for others that later come up over this same problem?

Comment: see my edit in the question :)

Comment: muchas gracias!